# Regex - How to select a specific character right before a number string in a text

Tags: regex

I want to capture a single character (in this case, letter v) standing right before a number string in a text.

For example: v1.0.0, v20.202.0, v10013, etc

Comment: Please specify language/framework you're trying to use

Comment: @VadimKotov I'm not sure about that. I'm using A Better File Rename [link](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) to rename files and there's a renaming feature using Regex.

Comment: I think then you question is more suitable for https://superuser.com/, because it is not that related to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead `(?=`to assert that what follows is a digit `\d`

[`v(?=\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/zhD7Da/1)